# Can mount afp share via mount_afp but not via Autofs

Tags: macos, mount, afp, automount, autofs

Current system, OSX 10.9.5

I've followed the instructions in [this MacWorld hint](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100203124656707) and by reading the [Apple doc for Autofs](http://images.apple.com/business/docs/Autofs.pdf) and [several](http://www.linux-consulting.com/Amd_AutoFS/autofs-5.html) [other](http://lowendmac.com/2009/introduction-to-autofs-in-mac-os-x/) [places](http://martinbay.net/automount-diskstation-shares-in-os-x/) but I can't get `autofs` to automagically mount a remote AFP share on my NAS box:

```
$ sudo ls -l /private/etc | grep auto
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel     149 28 Jun 09:35 auto_home
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel     256 24 Oct 13:39 auto_master
-rw-r--r--@  1 root   wheel      97 24 Oct 13:39 auto_nas
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel    1935 28 Jun 09:35 autofs.conf
```

#### /etc/auto_master

```
#
# Automounter master map
#
/-                                  auto_nas    -nosuid  # this one is mine
+auto_master                        # Use directory service
/net                                -hosts      -nobrowse,hidefromfinder,nosuid
/home                               auto_home   -nobrowse,hidefromfinder
/Network/Servers                    -fstab
/-                                  -static
```

#### /etc/auto_nas

```
/Users/USER/Shares/Public   -fstype=afp afp://USER:PASSWORD@nasbox.local/Public
```

The permissions on the `Shares` directory:

```
$ ls -al /Users/USER | grep Shares
drwxr-xr-x    3 USER  staff     102 24 Oct 13:31 Shares
```

I've put `nasbox.local` in `/etc/hosts` and can ping it fine. I update the automount (I've also rebooted, no dice).

```
$ sudo automount -vc
automount: /net updated
automount: /home updated
automount: no unmounts
```

and…

```
$ cd /Users/USER/Shares/Public
cd:cd:13: no such file or directory: /Users/USER/Shares/Public
```

but, if I use `mount_afp` it mounts the directory fine:

```
$ mkdir /Users/USER/Shares/Public
$ mount_afp afp://USER:PASSWORD@nasbox.local/Public /Users/USER/Shares/Public

$ ls -l /Users/USER/Shares/Public 
total 3718056
long list of file follows…
```

Would anyone know what part of the incantation I'm missing to get the magic to work? I've tried all the obvious stuff like making the `Public` directory prior to mount, and changing permissions to it and `Shares`, using direct maps, indirect maps, wildcards… I've still not got this to work :-/

Any help or insight will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please create a folder `Share` in the User folder and change your auto_master to

#### /etc/auto_master

```
#
# Automounter master map
#
+auto_master                        # Use directory service
/Users/User/Share           auto_nas
/net                                -hosts      -nobrowse,hidefromfinder,nosuid
/home                               auto_home   -nobrowse,hidefromfinder
/Network/Servers                    -fstab
/-                                  -static
```

and

#### /etc/auto_nas

```
Shared_Folder -fstype=afp afp://User:Password@ip/Shared_Folder
```

enter `sudo automount -vc` in Terminal with the output:

```
$ sudo automount -vc
automount: /Users/User/Share updated
automount: /net updated
automount: /home updated
automount: no unmounts
```

Please regard the additional output: **automount: /Users/User/Share updated**

**Both files need a trailing empty line** or it won't work and you'll get the following error:
`automount[pid]: map /etc/auto_master: line too long (max 4095 chars)` or
`automount[pid]: map /etc/auto_nas: line too long (max 4095 chars)`

(all tested and verified with a 10.9.5 client and 10.7.5 server)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. It was actually the trailing line that I was missing that seemed to make the difference, and I didn't get an error message without it, just silent failure. But now it works! Many thanks again.

Comment: Why did you delete your comment in http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/158083/mount-network-share-afp-smb-for-multiple-users-fast-user-switching?

Comment: @softandsafe because it was a totally wrong answer. i'm just working on a better one