# Change Connected Servers

Tags: network

I have two Synology Diskstations in my list of Connected Servers. Disk station-5 and Diskstation-8 (see image). Now I want to change the user name for these connected servers and I want these connected servers to connect when I boot my laptop or desktop. I simply cannot get it done. Every time the servers are not connected and when I try to connect the old user name appears. Anyone ?

[image]

Comment: Which kind of protocol do you use to mount your shares? afp, smb or nfs?

Comment: AFP. This always worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deleting the keychain entries with the old user name you may use several methods to mount your shares automatically:

1. Login Items:

   - mount the two shares with the new username/password and save the new password in the keychain
   - open System Preferences -> Users & Groups -> your current user -> Login Items
   - drag the two shares to the list
2. auto_mount:

   - check this [question and answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152712/can-mount-afp-share-via-mount-afp-but-not-via-autofs/153677#153677) and probably several others here at apple.se

Comment: ad 1. If I try to add the shares to the "login items" list I have to add all the folders on my disk stations ???

Comment: @JanScherders If you have several shares on one disk station it depends you. If you need a 2nd or a 3rd share immediately then yes. But after mounting the 1st all other shares on the disk station are also available via Side Bar -> Shares -> diskstation-x -> ...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the password is cleared in your login Keychain. Open the Keychain Access utility (spotlight > Keychain Access). IN the left hand panes, select **Keychains > login** and **Category > All items**. Now search for **diskstation** in the top right to filter the results.

<s>Delete the offending keychain entries.</s>

Change the username and password for these entries so as not to disrupt anything else going on with those servers.

Comment: that helped !! But now the disk station is not "automatically" connected. What I want is that the disk stations connect when I boot the laptop/desktop. How can I arrange that ? It used to do that ...

Comment: I have deleted the disk stations from my keychain. Now I can connect again to my disk stations with this new username. But I still have to "click" every time on the disk stations (shared servers) in finder to reconnect them when i want. How can I have the disk stations connected automatically and stay connected ?

Comment: You can add them in System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Items (for your user account)

Comment: If I try to add the shares to the "login items" list I have to add all the folders on my disk stations ???

Comment: Adding one share should add the server as a connection. Probably the thing to do originally (I'll edit my answer) was to have you *change* the username/password in the Keychain, not delete. That was shortsighted of me.