# Can I remove BootCamp HFS+ driver

Tags: bootcamp, driver, hfs+

So, I have an iMac 27" Late 2012, and I have just installed Windows 10 Home 64Bit through BootCamp. BootCamp comes along with several "support software", useful drivers made for Windows and Apple hardware. I have recently noticed that one of the drivers mounts and makes read-and-writeable drives that are formatted in HFS+, including my Mac drive (which appears read-only) and an external HDD I make backups to. Since I'm afraid of Windows Ransomware, I'd like to remove any access to HFS+ drivers from Windows side of things. Is there any way to remove (or at least disable) the driver that enables HFS+?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIK the Apple HFS+ drivers are read-only. You may have installed another read/write driver like Paragon.

To remove Apple HFS+ Driver:

1. Browse to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\
2. Move AppleHFS.sys & AppleMNT.sys to the Recycle Bin
3. Create a *Remove_AppleHFS.reg* file with a text editor like NotePad and the following content:

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   [-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\AppleHFS]

   [-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\AppleMNT]
   ```

   You may have to add a trailing empty line.

   Merging a reg file with the registry should work as following:

   - Click on Start and then Run...
   - Type in regedit, and then press OK
   - In regedit, click on File, and then Import
   - Enter the filename or otherwise locate the ".reg" file you want to enter, and press OK
   - The contents of that ".reg" file will be entered into the registry.
4. Restart

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please explain how I can Merge it with Windows registry (I never used Windows before, only GNU/Linux and Mac). Also, doing so am I REMOVING the driver or making a kind of "script" to DISABLE it?

Comment: @alex2003super Moving AppleHFS.sys & AppleMNT.sys to the Recycle Bin and emptying it removes the files. Removing the reg entries is the clean-up work to delete unknown reg entries.

Comment: paste that code into a file in notepad and save it with a .reg extension. Then double click on it to apply the changes to the registry.

Comment: And, what do you mean by "trailing empty line"?

Comment: @alex2003super Some files need a new empty line to work properly. But I can't show this properly because empty lines at the end of a code section are just suppressed in the presentation here! [Example](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/153677/93229)

Comment: This actually solved a long standing VSS-problem for me on my "genuine" Windows 10 machine also. It prevented restorepoints and also cloning and backups of the system partition, since many backup software uses VSS. Thanks!